# 質問・回答・スニペットのマークアップ練習場

Tags: サポート, markdown

これは、

- この質問自体を編集したり (信用度が100必要です)
- 回答を追加したり
- コメントを追加したり

など自由に使える質問です。

[英語版のSEメタにある同様の質問](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)を見ると、アートな回答も色々あっておもしろいです。

参考リンク:
[Markdown や HTML を使用して投稿を書式設定するには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)
[Markdown ヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)
[スタックオーバーフローで使えるHTMLタグ一覧はありますか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3499/9820)

Answer (score 10):

## レイアウトのテスト

`<pre>` と `スペース` での調整

```
     あなたとJAVA,
    今すぐダウンロー
         ド

無料Javaのダウンロード
```

※ スマートにセンタリングする方法はない？

---

`&nbsp;` での調整 とヒント `>!`

> [３０億のデバイスで動く](http://example.com/)
>
>              あなたとジャバ

---

↓ ヒント内に `<kbd>` がある場合の挙動は不審。

> <kbd>[有料Apple](http://example.com/)の[デバイスで動かず](http://example.com/)</kbd>

---

## 画像テスト

アクセスカウンタ

[image]

Answer (score 4):

コメントテスト用

123456789

Comment: `_文字_`のMarkupが日本語で使えない為、それを`*文字*`に変えるべきです。

Comment: 書式にうまく収まらない質問もあります。**主に意見を求める**質問や、回答ではなく**ディスカッションになりやすい**質問は、避けてください。

Comment: [Apache2
でパスワード保護したディレクトリにロボットが侵入](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6801/ap
ache2)

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20030623161822/http://www.epkowa.co.jp/linux/DLinfo.html

Comment: [リンク文字列に[スクエアブラケット]が入っている場合](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%8B%AC%E5%BC%A7#.E8.A7.92.E6.8B.AC.E5.BC.A7.EF.BC.BB.EF.BC.BD)

Comment: [リンク文字列に入っている\[スクエアブラケット\]を\\\[でエスケープした場合](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%8B%AC%E5%BC%A7#.E8.A7.92.E6.8B.AC.E5.BC.A7.EF.BC.BB.EF.BC.BD)

Comment: ___毎回___あなたのコメントが通知されます。

Comment: ___毎回___ あなたのコメントが通知されます。

Comment: ***毎回***あなたのコメントが通知されます。

Comment: コメントで `[edit]` と書くとその投稿へのリンクに自動変換されます：[edit]

Comment: 【リンクの練習用】 [ここ](https://paiza.io/help)を参照してください。

Answer (score 2):

リストを入れ子にすると`<br>`が現れる…？

- リスト1

  - リスト1-1
  - リスト1-2
- リスト2
- リスト3

  - リスト3-1
  - リスト3-2
  - リスト3-3
- リスト4

#### プレビューに出力されるHTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        リスト1<br>
        <ul>
            <li>リスト1-1</li><br>
            <li>リスト1-2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>リスト2</li>
    <li>
        リスト3<br>
        <ul>
            <li>リスト3-1</li><br>
            <li>リスト3-2</li><br>
            <li>リスト3-3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>リスト4</li>
</ul>
```

#### post後の回答として出力されるHTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        リスト1<br>
        <ul><br>
            <li>リスト1-1</li><br>
            <li>リスト1-2</li><br>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>リスト2</li>
    <li>
        リスト3<br>
        <ul><br>
            <li>リスト3-1</li><br>
            <li>リスト3-2</li><br>
            <li>リスト3-3</li><br>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>リスト4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

スニペットにすれば、SVGタグをそのまま貼り付けて、スニペット実行することで表示することが可能の模様。

以下の図はいずれも https://www.draw.io/ を利用して作成した。

---

こちらはIE11でうまく表示できない。ChromeやFirefoxなどは問題ない。EdgeもOK。

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="318px" height="458px" version="1.1" content="%3CmxGraphModel%20dx%3D%22979%22%20dy%3D%22741%22%20grid%3D%221%22%20gridSize%3D%2210%22%20guides%3D%221%22%20tooltips%3D%221%22%20connect%3D%221%22%20arrows%3D%221%22%20fold%3D%221%22%20page%3D%221%22%20pageScale%3D%221%22%20pageWidth%3D%22826%22%20pageHeight%3D%221169%22%20background%3D%22%23ffffff%22%20math%3D%220%22%3E%3Croot%3E%3CmxCell%20id%3D%220%22%2F%3E%3CmxCell%20id%3D%221%22%20parent%3D%220%22%2F%3E%3CmxCell%20id%3D%224%22%20value%3D%22Entity%20Object%22%20style%3D%22ellipse%3Bshape%3DumlEntity%3BwhiteSpace%3Dwrap%3Bhtml%3D1%3B%22%20parent%3D%221%22%20vertex%3D%221%22%3E%3CmxGeometry%20x%3D%2250%22%20y%3D%22140%22%20width%3D%2280%22%20height%3D%2280%22%20as%3D%22geometry%22%2F%3E%3C%2FmxCell%3E%3CmxCell%20id%3D%225%22%20value%3D%22Control%20Object%22%20style%3D%22ellipse%3Bshape%3DumlControl%3BwhiteSpace%3Dwrap%3Bhtml%3D1%3B%22%20parent%3D%221%22%20vertex%3D%221%22%3E%3CmxGeometry%20x%3D%22160%22%20y%3D%22140%22%20width%3D%2270%22%20height%3D%2280%22%20as%3D%22geometry%22%2F%3E%3C%2FmxCell%3E%3CmxCell%20id%3D%226%22%20value%3D%22Boundary%20Object%22%20style%3D%22shape%3DumlBoundary%3BwhiteSpace%3Dwrap%3Bhtml%3D1%3B%22%20parent%3D%221%22%20vertex%3D%221%22%3E%3CmxGeometry%20x%3D%22250%22%20y%3D%22140%22%20width%3D%22100%22%20height%3D%2280%22%20as%3D%22geometry%22%2F%3E%3C%2FmxCell%3E%3CmxCell%20id%3D%227%22%20value%3D%22Actor%22%20style%3D%22shape%3DumlActor%3BverticalLabelPosition%3Dbottom%3BlabelBackgroundColor%3D%23ffffff%3BverticalAlign%3Dtop%3Bhtml%3D1%3B%22%20parent%3D%221%22%20vertex%3D%221%22%3E%3CmxGeometry%20x%3D%22110%22%20y%3D%2240%22%20width%3D%2230%22%20height%3D%2260%22%20as%3D%22geometry%22%2F%3E%3C%2FmxCell%3E%3CmxCell%20id%3D%228%22%20value%3D%22Use%20Case%22%20style%3D%22ellipse%3BwhiteSpace%3Dwrap%3Bhtml%3D1%3B%22%20parent%3D%221%22%20vertex%3D%221%22%3E%3CmxGeometry%20x%3D%22190%22%20y%3D%2240%22%20width%3D%22140%22%20height%3D%2270%22%20as%3D%22geometry%22%2F%3E%3C%2FmxCell%3E%3CmxCell%20id%3D%2247037199db69eccc-8%22%20value%3D%22Classname%22%20style%3D%22swimlane%3Bhtml%3D1%3BfontStyle%3D1%3Balign%3Dcenter%3BverticalAlign%3Dtop%3BchildLayout%3DstackLayout%3Bhorizontal%3D1%3BstartSize%3D26%3BhorizontalStack%3D0%3BresizeParent%3D1%3BresizeLast%3D0%3Bcollapsible%3D1%3BmarginBottom%3D0%3BswimlaneFillColor%3D%23ffffff%3B%22%20parent%3D%221%22%20vertex%3D%221%22%3E%3CmxGeometry%20x%3D%22115%22%20y%3D%22244%22%20width%3D%22160%22%20height%3D%2290%22%20as%3D%22geometry%22%2F%3E%3C%2FmxCell%3E%3CmxCell%20id%3D%2247037199db69eccc-9%22%20value%3D%22%2B%20field%3A%20type%22%20style%3D%22text%3Bhtml%3D1%3BstrokeColor%3Dnone%3BfillColor%3Dnone%3Balign%3Dleft%3BverticalAlign%3Dtop%3BspacingLeft%3D4%3BspacingRight%3D4%3BwhiteSpace%3Dwrap%3Boverflow%3Dhidden%3Brotatable%3D0%3Bpoints%3D%5B%5B0%2C0.5%5D%2C%5B1%2C0.5%5D%5D%3BportConstraint%3Deastwest%3B%22%20parent%3D%2247037199db69eccc-8%22%20vertex%3D%221%22%3E%3CmxGeometry%20y%3D%2226%22%20width%3D%22160%22%20height%3D%2226%22%20as%3D%22geometry%22%2F%3E%3C%2FmxCell%3E%3CmxCell%20id%3D%2247037199db69eccc-10%22%20value%3D%22%22%20style%3D%22line%3Bhtml%3D1%3BstrokeWidth%3D1%3BfillColor%3Dnone%3Balign%3Dleft%3BverticalAlign%3Dmiddle%3BspacingTop%3D-1%3BspacingLeft%3D3%3BspacingRight%3D3%3Brotatable%3D0%3BlabelPosition%3Dright%3Bpoints%3D%5B%5D%3BportConstraint%3Deastwest%3B%22%20parent%3D%2247037199db69eccc-8%22%20vertex%3D%221%22%3E%3CmxGeometry%20y%3D%2252%22%20width%3D%22160%22%20height%3D%228%22%20as%3D%22geometry%22%2F%3E%3C%2FmxCell%3E%3CmxCell%20id%3D%2247037199db69eccc-11%22%20value%3D%22%2B%20method(type)%3A%20type%22%20style%3D%22text%3Bhtml%3D1%3BstrokeColor%3Dnone%3BfillColor%3Dnone%3Balign%3Dleft%3BverticalAlign%3Dtop%3BspacingLeft%3D4%3BspacingRight%3D4%3BwhiteSpace%3Dwrap%3Boverflow%3Dhidden%3Brotatable%3D0%3Bpoints%3D%5B%5B0%2C0.5%5D%2C%5B1%2C0.5%5D%5D%3BportConstraint%3Deastwest%3B%22%20parent%3D%2247037199db69eccc-8%22%20vertex%3D%221%22%3E%3CmxGeometry%20y%3D%2260%22%20width%3D%22160%22%20height%3D%2226%22%20as%3D%22geometry%22%2F%3E%3C%2FmxCell%3E%3CmxCell%20id%3D%2247037199db69eccc-12%22%20value%3D%22Classname%22%20style%3D%22swimlane%3Bhtml%3D1%3BfontStyle%3D1%3Balign%3Dcenter%3BverticalAlign%3Dtop%3BchildLayout%3DstackLayout%3Bhorizontal%3D1%3BstartSize%3D26%3BhorizontalStack%3D0%3BresizeParent%3D1%3BresizeLast%3D0%3Bcollapsible%3D1%3BmarginBottom%3D0%3BswimlaneFillColor%3D%23ffffff%3B%22%20parent%3D%221%22%20vertex%3D%221%22%3E%3CmxGeometry%20x%3D%2235%22%20y%3D%22405%22%20width%3D%22160%22%20height%3D%2290%22%20as%3D%22geometry%22%2F%3E%3C%2FmxCell%3E%3CmxCell%20id%3D%2247037199db69eccc-13%22%20value%3D%22%2B%20field%3A%20type%22%20style%3D%22text%3Bhtml%3D1%3BstrokeColor%3Dnone%3BfillColor%3Dnone%3Balign%3Dleft%3BverticalAlign%3Dtop%3BspacingLeft%3D4%3BspacingRight%3D4%3BwhiteSpace%3Dwrap%3Boverflow%3Dhidden%3Brotatable%3D0%3Bpoints%3D%5B%5B0%2C0.5%5D%2C%5B1%2C0.5%5D%5D%3BportConstraint%3Deastwest%3B%22%20parent%3D%2247037199db69eccc-12%22%20vertex%3D%221%22%3E%3CmxGeometry%20y%3D%2226%22%20width%3D%22160%22%20height%3D%2226%22%20as%3D%22geometry%22%2F%3E%3C%2FmxCell%3E%3CmxCell%20id%3D%2247037199db69eccc-14%22%20value%3D%22%22%20style%3D%22line%3Bhtml%3D1%3BstrokeWidth%3D1%3BfillColor%3Dnone%3Balign%3Dleft%3BverticalAlign%3Dmiddle%3BspacingTop%3D-1%3BspacingLeft%3D3%3BspacingRight%3D3%3Brotatable%3D0%3BlabelPosition%3Dright%3Bpoints%3D%5B%5D%3BportConstraint%3Deastwest%3B%22%20parent%3D%2247037199db69eccc-12%22%20vertex%3D%221%22%3E%3CmxGeometry%20y%3D%2252%22%20width%3D%22160%22%20height%3D%228%22%20as%3D%22geometry%22%2F%3E%3C%2FmxCell%3E%3CmxCell%20id%3D%2247037199db69eccc-15%22%20value%3D%22%2B%20method(type)%3A%20type%22%20style%3D%22text%3Bhtml%3D1%3BstrokeColor%3Dnone%3BfillColor%3Dnone%3Balign%3Dleft%3BverticalAlign%3Dtop%3BspacingLeft%3D4%3BspacingRight%3D4%3BwhiteSpace%3Dwrap%3Boverflow%3Dhidden%3Brotatable%3D0%3Bpoints%3D%5B%5B0%2C0.5%5D%2C%5B1%2C0.5%5D%5D%3BportConstraint%3Deastwest%3B%22%20parent%3D%2247037199db69eccc-12%22%20vertex%3D%221%22%3E%3CmxGeometry%20y%3D%2260%22%20width%3D%22160%22%20height%3D%2226%22%20as%3D%22geometry%22%2F%3E%3C%2FmxCell%3E%3CmxCell%20id%3D%2247037199db69eccc-16%22%20value%3D%22Extends%22%20style%3D%22endArrow%3Dblock%3BendSize%3D16%3BendFill%3D0%3Bhtml%3D1%3B%22%20parent%3D%221%22%20source%3D%2247037199db69eccc-12%22%20target%3D%2247037199db69eccc-8%22%20edge%3D%221%22%3E%3CmxGeometry%20width%3D%22160%22%20relative%3D%221%22%20as%3D%22geometry%22%3E%3CmxPoint%20x%3D%22250%22%20y%3D%22540%22%20as%3D%22sourcePoint%22%2F%3E%3CmxPoint%20x%3D%22410%22%20y%3D%22540%22%20as%3D%22targetPoint%22%2F%3E%3C%2FmxGeometry%3E%3C%2FmxCell%3E%3C%2Froot%3E%3C%2FmxGraphModel%3E" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><defs/><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)"><ellipse cx="56" cy="141" rx="40" ry="40" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" pointer-events="none"/><path d="M 26 181 L 86 181" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="none"/><g transform="translate(22,135)"><switch><foreignObject style="overflow:visible;" pointer-events="all" width="68" height="12" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 1.2; vertical-align: top; width: 69px; white-space: nowrap; text-align: center;"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display:inline-block;text-align:inherit;text-decoration:inherit;">Entity Object</div></div></foreignObject><text x="34" y="12" fill="#000000" text-anchor="middle" font-size="12px" font-family="Helvetica">[Not supported by viewer]</text></switch></g><path d="M 152.25 112 L 169.75 101" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="none"/><ellipse cx="161" cy="146" rx="35" ry="35" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" pointer-events="none"/><path d="M 152.25 112 L 169.75 121" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="none"/><g transform="translate(128,133)"><switch><foreignObject style="overflow:visible;" pointer-events="all" width="66" height="26" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 1.2; vertical-align: top; width: 66px; white-space: normal; text-align: center;"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display:inline-block;text-align:inherit;text-decoration:inherit;">Control Object</div></div></foreignObject><text x="33" y="19" fill="#000000" text-anchor="middle" font-size="12px" font-family="Helvetica">[Not supported by viewer]</text></switch></g><path d="M 216 121 L 216 161" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="none"/><path d="M 216 141 L 232.67 141" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="none"/><ellipse cx="274" cy="141" rx="41.666666666666664" ry="40" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" pointer-events="none"/><g transform="translate(234,128)"><switch><foreignObject style="overflow:visible;" pointer-events="all" width="80" height="26" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 1.2; vertical-align: top; width: 80px; white-space: normal; text-align: center;"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display:inline-block;text-align:inherit;text-decoration:inherit;">Boundary Object</div></div></foreignObject><text x="40" y="19" fill="#000000" text-anchor="middle" font-size="12px" font-family="Helvetica">[Not supported by viewer]</text></switch></g><ellipse cx="91" cy="9" rx="7.5" ry="7.5" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" pointer-events="none"/><path d="M 91 16 L 91 41 M 91 21 L 76 21 M 91 21 L 106 21 M 91 41 L 76 61 M 91 41 L 106 61" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="none"/><g transform="translate(77,69)"><switch><foreignObject style="overflow:visible;" pointer-events="all" width="28" height="12" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 1.2; vertical-align: top; white-space: nowrap; text-align: center;"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display:inline-block;text-align:inherit;text-decoration:inherit;background-color:#ffffff;">Actor</div></div></foreignObject><text x="14" y="12" fill="#000000" text-anchor="middle" font-size="12px" font-family="Helvetica">[Not supported by viewer]</text></switch></g><ellipse cx="226" cy="36" rx="70" ry="35" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" pointer-events="none"/><g transform="translate(199,30)"><switch><foreignObject style="overflow:visible;" pointer-events="all" width="54" height="12" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 1.2; vertical-align: top; width: 55px; white-space: nowrap; text-align: center;"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display:inline-block;text-align:inherit;text-decoration:inherit;">Use Case</div></div></foreignObject><text x="27" y="12" fill="#000000" text-anchor="middle" font-size="12px" font-family="Helvetica">[Not supported by viewer]</text></switch></g><rect x="81" y="205" width="160" height="90" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" pointer-events="none"/><path d="M 81 231 L 81 205 L 241 205 L 241 231 Z" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="none"/><g transform="translate(129,213)"><switch><foreignObject style="overflow:visible;" pointer-events="all" width="65" height="12" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 1.2; vertical-align: top; white-space: nowrap; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display:inline-block;text-align:inherit;text-decoration:inherit;">Classname</div></div></foreignObject><text x="33" y="12" fill="#000000" text-anchor="middle" font-size="12px" font-family="Helvetica" font-weight="bold">[Not supported by viewer]</text></switch></g><g transform="translate(87,238)"><switch><foreignObject style="overflow:visible;" pointer-events="all" width="62" height="12" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 1.2; vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; max-height: 22px; max-width: 148px; width: 63px; white-space: normal;"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display:inline-block;text-align:inherit;text-decoration:inherit;">+ field: type</div></div></foreignObject><text x="31" y="12" fill="#000000" text-anchor="middle" font-size="12px" font-family="Helvetica">[Not supported by viewer]</text></switch></g><path d="M 81 261 L 241 261" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="none"/><g transform="translate(87,272)"><switch><foreignObject style="overflow:visible;" pointer-events="all" width="111" height="12" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 1.2; vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; max-height: 22px; max-width: 148px; width: 112px; white-space: normal;"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display:inline-block;text-align:inherit;text-decoration:inherit;">+ method(type): type</div></div></foreignObject><text x="56" y="12" fill="#000000" text-anchor="middle" font-size="12px" font-family="Helvetica">[Not supported by viewer]</text></switch></g><rect x="1" y="366" width="160" height="90" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" pointer-events="none"/><path d="M 1 392 L 1 366 L 161 366 L 161 392 Z" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="none"/><g transform="translate(49,374)"><switch><foreignObject style="overflow:visible;" pointer-events="all" width="65" height="12" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 1.2; vertical-align: top; white-space: nowrap; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display:inline-block;text-align:inherit;text-decoration:inherit;">Classname</div></div></foreignObject><text x="33" y="12" fill="#000000" text-anchor="middle" font-size="12px" font-family="Helvetica" font-weight="bold">[Not supported by viewer]</text></switch></g><g transform="translate(7,399)"><switch><foreignObject style="overflow:visible;" pointer-events="all" width="62" height="12" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 1.2; vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; max-height: 22px; max-width: 148px; width: 63px; white-space: normal;"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display:inline-block;text-align:inherit;text-decoration:inherit;">+ field: type</div></div></foreignObject><text x="31" y="12" fill="#000000" text-anchor="middle" font-size="12px" font-family="Helvetica">[Not supported by viewer]</text></switch></g><path d="M 1 422 L 161 422" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="none"/><g transform="translate(7,433)"><switch><foreignObject style="overflow:visible;" pointer-events="all" width="111" height="12" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 1.2; vertical-align: top; overflow: hidden; max-height: 22px; max-width: 148px; width: 112px; white-space: normal;"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display:inline-block;text-align:inherit;text-decoration:inherit;">+ method(type): type</div></div></foreignObject><text x="56" y="12" fill="#000000" text-anchor="middle" font-size="12px" font-family="Helvetica">[Not supported by viewer]</text></switch></g><path d="M 103.36 366 L 130.58 311.23" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="none"/><path d="M 138.14 296 L 138.19 315.01 L 122.97 307.44 Z" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="none"/><g transform="translate(101,325)"><switch><foreignObject style="overflow:visible;" pointer-events="all" width="40" height="11" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: inline-block; font-size: 11px; font-family: Helvetica; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 1.2; vertical-align: top; white-space: nowrap; text-align: center;"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display:inline-block;text-align:inherit;text-decoration:inherit;background-color:#ffffff;">Extends</div></div></foreignObject><text x="20" y="11" fill="#000000" text-anchor="middle" font-size="11px" font-family="Helvetica">[Not supported by viewer]</text></switch></g></g></svg>
```

---

こちらはIE11でも文字部分が表示できるように問題を回避したもの。
下記の記事を元に文字出力時の設定を変更した。
その代わりに文字が絵と交わったりする。

[Why does the text of SVG export sometimes not display correctly in IE and some SVG editors? - draw.io Support](https://support.draw.io/questions/1671290/why-does-the-text-of-svg-export-sometimes-not-display-correctly-in-ie-and-some-svg-editors)

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="322px" height="458px" version="1.1" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><defs><clipPath id="mx-clip-85-236-152-26-0"><rect x="85" y="236" width="152" height="26"/></clipPath><clipPath id="mx-clip-85-270-152-26-0"><rect x="85" y="270" width="152" height="26"/></clipPath><clipPath id="mx-clip-5-397-152-26-0"><rect x="5" y="397" width="152" height="26"/></clipPath><clipPath id="mx-clip-5-431-152-26-0"><rect x="5" y="431" width="152" height="26"/></clipPath></defs><g transform="translate(0.5,0.5)"><ellipse cx="56" cy="141" rx="40" ry="40" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" pointer-events="none"/><path d="M 26 181 L 86 181" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="none"/><g fill="#000000" font-family="Helvetica" text-anchor="middle" font-size="12px"><text x="56" y="145">Entity Object</text></g><path d="M 152.25 112 L 169.75 101" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="none"/><ellipse cx="161" cy="146" rx="35" ry="35" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" pointer-events="none"/><path d="M 152.25 112 L 169.75 121" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="none"/><g fill="#000000" font-family="Helvetica" text-anchor="middle" font-size="12px"><text x="161" y="149.88">Control Object</text></g><path d="M 216 121 L 216 161" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="none"/><path d="M 216 141 L 232.67 141" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="none"/><ellipse cx="274" cy="141" rx="41.666666666666664" ry="40" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" pointer-events="none"/><g fill="#000000" font-family="Helvetica" text-anchor="middle" font-size="12px"><text x="274.17" y="145">Boundary Object</text></g><path d="M 91 61 L 91 81 L 56 81 L 56 94.63" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="none"/><path d="M 56 99.88 L 52.5 92.88 L 56 94.63 L 59.5 92.88 Z" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="none"/><ellipse cx="91" cy="9" rx="7.5" ry="7.5" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" pointer-events="none"/><path d="M 91 16 L 91 41 M 91 21 L 76 21 M 91 21 L 106 21 M 91 41 L 76 61 M 91 41 L 106 61" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="none"/><g fill="#000000" font-family="Helvetica" text-anchor="middle" font-size="12px"><rect fill="#ffffff" stroke="none" x="77" y="70" width="30" height="15" stroke-width="0"/><text x="91" y="80">Actor</text></g><ellipse cx="226" cy="36" rx="70" ry="35" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" pointer-events="none"/><g fill="#000000" font-family="Helvetica" text-anchor="middle" font-size="12px"><text x="226" y="40">Use Case</text></g><rect x="81" y="205" width="160" height="90" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" pointer-events="none"/><path d="M 81 231 L 81 205 L 241 205 L 241 231 Z" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="none"/><g fill="#000000" font-family="Helvetica" font-weight="bold" text-anchor="middle" font-size="12px"><text x="161" y="224">Classname</text></g><g fill="#000000" font-family="Helvetica" clip-path="url(#mx-clip-85-236-152-26-0)" font-size="12px"><text x="87" y="249">+ field: type</text></g><path d="M 81 261 L 241 261" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="none"/><g fill="#000000" font-family="Helvetica" clip-path="url(#mx-clip-85-270-152-26-0)" font-size="12px"><text x="87" y="283">+ method(type): type</text></g><rect x="1" y="366" width="160" height="90" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" pointer-events="none"/><path d="M 1 392 L 1 366 L 161 366 L 161 392 Z" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="none"/><g fill="#000000" font-family="Helvetica" font-weight="bold" text-anchor="middle" font-size="12px"><text x="81" y="385">Classname</text></g><g fill="#000000" font-family="Helvetica" clip-path="url(#mx-clip-5-397-152-26-0)" font-size="12px"><text x="7" y="410">+ field: type</text></g><path d="M 1 422 L 161 422" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="none"/><g fill="#000000" font-family="Helvetica" clip-path="url(#mx-clip-5-431-152-26-0)" font-size="12px"><text x="7" y="444">+ method(type): type</text></g><path d="M 103.36 366 L 130.58 311.23" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="none"/><path d="M 138.14 296 L 138.19 315.01 L 122.97 307.44 Z" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="none"/><g fill="#000000" font-family="Helvetica" text-anchor="middle" font-size="11px"><rect fill="#ffffff" stroke="none" x="101" y="324" width="42" height="14" stroke-width="0"/><text x="121.16" y="333.68">Extends</text></g></g></svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

[スポイラー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#spoilers)のテストです。

先頭に `>!` を入れるとスポイラーになります。ヒントだけ出して答えを隠すときに便利。

> マウスオーバーすると表示されます。
>  複数行書くことができます。
>  クリック/タップすると表示を固定することができます。
>  モバイル版やアプリ版でも隠れる(らしい)。
>  **太字**や[リンク](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)もできます。

### ソースコードを隠す

インラインコードは通常通りバックティックで囲うとスポイラーの中に書けます。

> インラインコードは `このように` 書けます。

コードブロックは以下の手順で書けます。

1. ソースコード中の `<`, `>` を `&lt;`, `&gt;` に置換する。
2. 全ての行頭に `>!` を追加する。
3. `<pre><code>` ... `</code></pre>` で囲う。

> ```
> int main() {
>
>     printf("Hello, world!\n");
>
>     return 0;
>
> }
> ```

- HTML タグを直接書くのはやや汚いですが、現状この方法しか無い模様: [How can I put a whole code block in spoiler text?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105735)
- `>!` の後に半角スペースを入れるかどうかに注意。code タグ内では入れない。インデントがずれるので。
- コードの各行の間に謎の空行が入る。Meta Stack Exchange では全く同じ Markdown ソースでも空行が入らない。SOja では HTML レベルで `<br>` が入ってしまっている。[バグ？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2875/19110)

### リスト/引用/タイトルを隠す

コード同様、現状では HTML タグを直接書くことになるようです: [Spoilers don't format well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116613)

> #### タイトル
>
> ---
>
> 段落
>
> - リストも
>
> 1. 書けます
>
> > 引用ブロック
> >
> > 1. ...の中にネストしたリスト

Answer (score 1):

## コード記法についてのテストをさせてください。

### その0 : ``` `` ``` によるインライン

ワンライナー: `def fact(n: Int): Int = if (n <= 0) 1 else n * fact(n-1)`

### その1 : 行頭にスペース 4つ

`ここに↓ <!-- language: lang-scala --> がある`

```scala
import scala.annotation.tailrec
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    def factorial_tailrec(n: Int): Int = {
      @tailrec
      def loop(acc: Int, n: Int): Int = {
        if (n <= 0) acc
        else loop(acc * n, n-1)
      }
      loop(1, n)
    }

    println(s"fact: ${factorial_tailrec(10)}")
  }
}
```

### その2 : ```` ``` ```` による拡張記法

```prolog
% コード記法のテスト
人間(ソクラテス).
人間(アリストテレス).

死ぬ(X) :- 人間(X).

:- 死ぬ(X), println(X), falt; true.

?- 死ぬ(X).
X = ソクラテス ;
X = アリストテレス
```

### その3 : HTML `<pre><code>`

`↓ に <!-- language: lang-bash --> がある`

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Hello shellscript!'
```

Comment: *abc* *※日本語* **ABC** **※※日本語** 文中では*スペース*を**空けないと**だめでもなかった。

Comment: `<!-- language: lang-bash -->` の前に空改行をつけると有効になりますよ。

Comment: `<!-- language: lang-bash -->` の前後は空改行で空ける必要があるようでした。修正しました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

[snippet](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) は動く…？

`<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false-->`, `<!-- end snippet-->`  でくくって，間を `<!-- language: lang-html -->` などで区切るとこうなる

```js
alert("hi!");
```

```css
.hello {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="hello">すたっく・おうばーふろう！</div>
```

Comment: meta じゃないほうでは [使えるようになってる](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/221) みたいですね． (snippet では検索していたんですが[ひっかからなかった](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/1617/2901) 模様．）

Comment: [metaでも使えるように](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/221/stack-snippets-%e3%82%92%e4%bd%bf%e3%81%88%e3%82%8b%e3%82%88%e3%81%86%e3%81%ab%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6%e3%81%bb%e3%81%97%e3%81%84/1461?noredirect=1#comment590_1461)なりました

Comment: @ento ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

「スタック・オーバーフローのロゴ」の埋め込み画像です。スニペット用。 [この回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/5599/4978)を作るときに使用しました。

```html
<img width="158" height="158" title="Stack Overflow" alt="Stack Overflow" src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
```

Answer (score 1):

> つけすぎ何もクラリネットからいいたて夕方のゴーシュの耳たちを考え第一野ねずみ屋の病気から弾きて来ましまし。セロはいまきながら来た。

[「すぐ使えるダミーテキスト - 宮沢賢治「セロ弾きのゴーシュ」」より](http://lipsum.sugutsukaeru.jp/index.cgi)より。

Answer (score 1):

MathJax のテスト

If $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is decreasing in $(0,\infty)$, prove that $f(a+b) \leq f(a) + f(b)$ for $a,b >0$

そのままでは認識しないが、強引にスニペットにすると表示できる。

```html
<script src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full"></script>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({"HTML-CSS": { preferredFont: "TeX", availableFonts:["STIX","TeX"], linebreaks: { automatic:true }, EqnChunk:(MathJax.Hub.Browser.isMobile ? 10 : 50) }, tex2jax: { inlineMath: [ ["$", "$"], ["\\\\(","\\\\)"] ], displayMath: [ ["$$","$$"], ["\\[", "\\]"] ], processEscapes: true, ignoreClass: "tex2jax_ignore|dno" }, TeX: { noUndefined: { attributes: { mathcolor: "red", mathbackground: "#FFEEEE", mathsize: "90%" } }, Macros: { href: "{}" } }, messageStyle: "none" });
</script>

If $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is decreasing in $(0,\infty)$, prove that $f(a+b) \leq f(a) + f(b)$ for $a,b >0$

$$f(x,y)=\int_0^\infty dp\int_0^\infty dq \frac{pqf(p,q)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
```

Answer (score 1):

ノーブレークスペースのテスト

# `&nbsp;`四つで字下げ
    print("Hello World!");

---

# U+00A0 四つで字下げ。IMEの文字コード入力機能で挿入。
# 上記をコピペした。この空白文字はコピペ出来ない。普通のスペースになる。

---

# U+00A0で字下げしてもコードサンプルにならない。
    # 編集画面ではただの空白のため気付きにくい

---

分かち書きの無しの強調

- `*` （ok）
  強調*テスト*です
- `**` (ok)
  強調**テスト**です
- `***` (ok —— 以前のパーサーではNGだった)
  強調***テスト***です
- `_` (NG)
  強調_テスト_です
- `__` (NG)
  強調__テスト__です
- `___` (NG)
  強調___テスト___です

---

`「 」` 内の強調

- `*` (ok) (コメントではNG)
  強調「*テスト*」です
- `**` (ok) (コメントではNG)
  強調「**テスト**」です
- `***` (ok) (コメントではNG)
  強調「***テスト***」です

---

URL(全角記号との空白なし)：https://example.com/
URL(半角記号との空白なし):https://example.com/
URL(空白あり): https://example.com/

---

[テキスト](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: `「 」` 内の強調 - `*`: 「*テスト*」 `**`:「**テスト**」

Answer (score 1):

[image: ロゴ]
超適当なAA

```
      Spanish    language 
    stackoverflowstackoverflow
 English Language&Usage Travel
Game Development  Stack Exchange
SuperUserServerFaultMathOverflow
 Ask Ubuntu Unix&Linux StackApps 
   Japanese Language Academia
     WordPress Development
      Android  Enthusiasts 
       Movies&TV Bicycles          
           Programmers
             SE SO
```

Answer (score 1):

タグ
[java](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) [完了](/questions/tagged/%e5%ae%8c%e4%ba%86)

キー
<kbd>Enter</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd>

答え

> あああ

Answer (score 1):

HTML TEST - 広告を貼り付ける。
[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Google]

snippet:

```html
<a href="http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/101667/google?referrer=MvZx-da8LAnLYejQCZKwpg2"><img src="http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/101667.png" width="300" height="250" alt="Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Google" /></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

console.logテスト

```js
console_dot();
function console_dot(){var _=['transparent','000000','ff7373'];
for(var $_ in _){eval('var _'+$_+"='background-color:#"+_[$_]+"';");};
var _c='%c​​%c​%c​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​%c​%c​​​​​​​​​​​​\n​%c​%c​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​%c​%c​​​​​​​​​​​\n​%c​%c​​​%c​%c​​​​​​​​​​​​​%c​%c​​​%c​%c​​​​​%c​​%c​%c​​%c​\n%c​%c​​​%c​%c​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​%c​%c​​​%c​%c​​​%c​​​​​​​\n%c​%c​​​​​​%c​%c​​​​​​​​​%c​%c​​​​​​%c​%c​​​%c​​​​​​​\n%c​%c​​​​​​%c​%c​​​​​​​​​%c​%c​​​​​​%c​%c​​​​%c​​​​​%c​\n%c​%c​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​%c​%c​​​​​%c​​​%c​​\n​%c​%c​​​%c​​%c​​​%c​%c​%c​%c​%c​%c​​​%c​​%c​​​%c​%c​​​​​​​%c​%c​​​\n​%c​%c​​​​​​​​%c​​%c​%c​​%c​​​​​​​​%c​%c​​​​​​​​​​​\n​​%c​%c​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​%c​%c​​​​​​​​​​​​\n';_c = _c.replace(/​/g,'  ');
console.log(_c,_0,_1,_0,_1,_0,_1,_0,_1,_0,_1,_0,_1,_0,_1,_0,_1,_0,_2,_0,_2,_0,_1,_0,_1,_0,_1,_0,_1,_0,_2,_1,_0,_1,_0,_1,_0,_1,_0,_2,_1,_0,_1,_0,_1,_0,_1,_0,_2,_0,_1,_0,_1,_0,_2,_0,_1,_0,_2,_0,_1,_0,_1,_0,_1,_0,_2,_0,_1,_0,_2,_0,_1,_0,_1,_0,_1,_0,_1,_0,_1,_0,_1,_0);};
```

Answer (score 0):

テキスト

1. aaa

```
text
```

2. bbb

```
text
```

---

編集時のプレビューでは 1 番目の項目もリストになるが、実際にはリストになっていない。これはリストの前にテキストがある場合に発生する。どちらが正しい動作なのだろう？

Answer (score 0):

Markdownの[参照リンク](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#reference-style-links)の構文テスト

[:http...](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)
[: http...](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)
[:  http...](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)
:　http...

参照リンク(Reference style links)では`:`の後ろにスペースを入れられます。
このスペースが全角の場合、編集プレビューではリンクに見えますが、実投稿ではリンクが消えてしまうようです。

Answer (score 0):

サイト初心者に対するUX、翻訳状況などを調査するための投稿です。