# 人間かどうかを証明するポップアップが明朝体になる

Tags: バグ, 完了, デザイン

### 再現手順:

1. [質問・回答・スニペットのマークアップ練習場](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331/%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%82%84%E5%9B%9E%E7%AD%94%E3%81%AE%E3%83%9E%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E3%81%AE%E7%B7%B4%E7%BF%92%E7%94%A8%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F?captcha=1) にアクセスする
2. 質問の編集リンクをクリックし、保存しようとする

### 出てくるポップアップ:

[image: 明朝体のポップアップ]

### 期待する見た目:

[image: ゴシック体のポップアップ]

サイト内の他の文言と同じように、ゴシック体のフォントであることを期待します。

### 原因:

`body`の外側にポップアップがあり、`html`要素には`font-family`の指定がないためと考えられます。

[image: html直下にいるポップアップ]

### 修正方法の推測:

`loadPopup`の引数に与えるパラメータで、ターゲットを`"appendTo"`キーで指定しているのを`"target"`に変えるとよさそうに見えます。

http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full.ja.js?v=6948b684e372

```
StackExchange.captcha = function() {
  ...
  function e(e, n) {
    $("body").loadPopup({"html": i,"appendTo": $("body"),"lightbox": !0,"loaded": function(e) {
      t(e, n)
    }})
  }
  ...
}()
```

`loadPopup`内では`.target`でポップアップの追加対象を取得しています。

http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.ja.js?v=d52350c9ac8a

```
"loadPopup": function(t) {
  var n = $.Deferred(), i = this, a = t.target || i.parent();
```

Mac OS X / Google Chrome 最新で確認しました。

Comment: 念のため、問題はフォントがサイトの他の部分と異なることですか？

Comment: @jmac はい、そうです。期待する見た目について補足しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed with the next build (build rev `2015.2.19.2316`), the popup should be correctly appended to the `<body>`, not after it.