# 質問に対するコメントの表示位置が２箇所に分かれているのはなぜですか？

Tags: サポート

先ほど御社サービスに登録させていただきました。よろしくお願いいたします。
さて、早速なのですが、利用方法について質問がありましたので、「メタ」のほうに投稿させていただきます。

質問のページにおいて、質問に対するコメントが、以下の２箇所に書かれていることに気づきました：

- その質問の直下に、小さな字で
- 線で区切られて、大きな文字で（掲示板のスレッド表示のように）

ツアーを見たのですが、これらがなにを区別しているのかがよく分かりませんでした。そこでお伺いしたいのですが：

- なぜ、コメントの表示箇所が複数あるのでしょうか？（＝全てをひとつのスレッドにまとめない理由はなんでしょうか？）
- 表示位置は、管理人の方が投稿したコメントの内容を吟味した結果決定するのでしょうか？　それとも、コメントの投稿者が指定できるのでしょうか？

お忙しいところ恐縮ですが、ご回答いただければ幸いです。
それでは、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 補足:回答を投稿をクリックして回答しても、短い回答はコメントになります。例:〜をしてください。[参考](http://example.com/example.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laclipさんの回答にある通り、「回答」と「コメント」が区別されています。
（私は Stack Exchange Inc の社員ではないです。一利用者です。念の為。）

#### 回答

> 線で区切られて、大きな文字で

書かれているのは、「回答」です。
StackOverflow では「質問」とこの「回答」がメインです。

#### コメント

> その質問の直下に、小さな字で

書かれているのは、その質問に対する「コメント」です。
「コメント」は質問だけでなく、回答にも付けられる物です。

コメントは補助的な扱いになります。
自分の質問や回答を訂正したり、情報を追加する際は、コメントでなくその投稿自体を編集出来ます。
質問に対する答がある場合はコメントでなく「回答」を書きます。
既存の投稿を見ていて、新たな質問が生まれた場合は、その既存の投稿にコメントするのではなく「質問」を書きます。

> コメントとは、質問または回答に残される一時的な「付箋」のメモです。コメントには賛成投票したり (反対投票はできません)
>   通報したりできますが、信用度は発生しません。リビジョン履歴はなく、削除されると永遠になくなります。
>
> 自分の投稿にはいつでもコメントでき、質問の一部にもコメントできます。しかし、他のユーザーの投稿にコメントを残すのは権限が必要です。
>   https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

> コメントを使って、情報の追加を依頼したり、質問または回答を明確にします。
>
> あなた自身の質問や回答にはいつでもコメントできます。信用度 50 点を獲得すると、どのユーザーの投稿にでもコメント出来るようになります。
>   https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour

#### 分かれている理由

> なぜ、コメントの表示箇所が複数あるのでしょうか？

上の通り、質問に対するレスポンスは「コメント」と「回答」として区別されています。

- 「回答」しか無かった場合
  例えば、質問が不明瞭であると感じ、質問者から追加の情報を聞き出したい事があります。
  その際は質問者へ質問する事になりますが、「質問者への質問」を「回答」として書けばカオスです。
  さらに質問者がその「質問者への質問」を理解出来なかった場合、「『質問者への質問』として書かれた回答への質問」を「自分の質問に対する回答」として書く事も予想され、カオスは拡大していきます。
- 「コメント」しか無かった場合
  上から時系列順に読んでいけば、会話を聞くのと同じですから、混乱は無いかも知れません。
  しかし、最終的に出された答が、やりとりの中に埋もれてしまう事になります。
  結果として、後から読みに来た人には大変使いづらいサイトになります。

#### どちらにするか誰が決めるのか

> 表示位置は、管理人の方が投稿したコメントの内容を吟味した結果決定するのでしょうか？　それとも、コメントの投稿者が指定できるのでしょうか？

投稿者が自分が何をしたいか考え、決定します。
「回答を投稿」という操作をすれば、回答になります。
「コメントを追加」という操作をすれば、コメントになります。

必要なら [質問・回答・スニペットのマークアップ練習場](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331/3054) で練習出来ます。

Answer (score 2):

> 表示位置は、コメントの投稿者が指定できるのでしょうか？

コメントというくくりではそのような事はできません。

> 線で区切られて、大きな文字で

基本的にはこちらの表記が回答になるからです。