# "このアカウントからの回答は受け付けていません" このメッセージが表示された時はどうすれば良いですか？

Tags: サポート, よくある質問の案

これを参考にしました：[What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/332584)
質問・回答しようとしたら、

> このアカウントからの質問は受け付けていません。詳細については、[ヘルプ センター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)をご覧ください。

> このアカウントからの回答は受け付けていません。詳細については、[ヘルプ センター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans)をご覧ください。

と表示されます。

- なぜ表示されるのですか？
- 削除された質問も低品質な投稿に含まれますか?
- 質問・回答が受け付けられないのとアカウントの凍結は同じですか？
- どうやってこれを避けるのですか？
- 禁止が解けるまでどれくらい待てばよいですか？禁止を解くにはどうすればいいのですか？
- 新しいアカウントを作って避けることはできますか？
- ほかのサイトで質問しました、そして正しいサイトに移行されました！
- Metaでも同じようになりますか？

Comment: タイトル「このメッセージが表示された時に何ができますか？」→「このメッセージが表示されたらどうすればいいですか?」

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## なぜ表示されるのですか？

[ツアー](//ja.stackoverflow.com/tour)に記載されている通り、Stack Exchangeは質問と回答のネットワークサイトで、フォーラムではありません。
これはすべての投稿が訪問者にも利益を与えるという‌​ことです。これを推し進め、そして回答者を離れさせる[Help vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) <sup>*1</sup> を防ぐために、質の低い質問や回答はブロックされます。これは以下のユーザーも含まれます。

- うまく文章が書けないユーザー
- とても簡単なことでも検索しないユーザー
- 何をしようとしているか説明しないユーザー

極端に質の悪い投稿の履歴を持つユーザーのアカウント、IPからの投稿をブロックする[自動フィルター](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system/60294#60294)が設置されています。

ブロックの基準は非公開ですが、一部はほかのユーザーからのマイナス投票が基準になっています。他のユーザーが一貫的に低評価をするようなら、その理由を特定すべきです。
たくさん質の悪い質問・回答を投稿すると、これ以上の質問、回答が禁止され、このエラーメッセージが表示されます。

## 悪い評価を受けた投稿を削除してもいいですか？

**投稿がマイナス投票やクローズされたという記録は、その投稿を削除してもアカウントに残ります**。可能なら、削除する代わりに修正してください。さらに、削除自体は、30日以内の時や、ほかのユーザーが回答や質問のモデレートをしているときに削除されたらカウントされます。

最後に、削除された質問はいつも投稿禁止に導きます。

投稿を削除しても構いません。しかし、投稿の大部分があなた自身もしくはコミュニティによって削除された場合、このサイトには適していないようです。質問を掲示することは、それを読んだユーザー、編集するユーザー、または回答するユーザーの時間を使います。そのため、削除された質問はフィルタに影響を与えます。

アカウントには削除済みの古い投稿が多数含まれているかもしれないことに注意してください。自動削除された古い低スコアの質問はすべてモデレーターにのみ表示されます。

## 質問・回答禁止はアカウントの凍結と同じですか？

いいえ、凍結は手動で、質問・回答が投稿できなくなる一時的なペナルティです。コメント・投票を含む全ての権限は、信用度を１にすることで使えなくします。これはほかのユーザーにもわかります。

投稿禁止は自動的で、禁止されている権限以外は使えます。

## どうやってこれを避けるのですか？

[ヘルプセンター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help)、特に[質問について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)と、[Stack Exchangeのモデル](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange)を読んでください。質問前には調べてください。それでもわからなければ、*あなたの質問に力を入れて書きましょう*。
すべての質問には、ほかの訪問者にとっても価値のあるものとされています。そのため質問の多くが回答を得られない、マイナス投票される、クローズされる、削除されるなら、明らかに要求された品質を満たせていません。なぜそうなるのかを理解し、学習してください。同じ質問を再投稿しないでください。

もしよい質問の基準が分からないなら、ヒントがあります：

- [良い質問をするには?](//ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - ヘルプセンター
- [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) - Jon Skeet
- [How to Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) - Eric S. Raymond

  - [賢く質問する方法](http://www.ranvis.com/articles/smart-questions.ja.html)(日本語訳) -　SATO Kentaro
- [Getting Answers](http://www.mikeash.com/getting_answers.html)

投稿のマークアップ・整形について：

- [Markdown ヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)
- [質問や回答に書いたソースコードをきれいに表示したい](//meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/2069/3054)
- [質問・回答・スニペットのマークアップ練習場](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331/15185)

## 禁止が解けるまでどれくらい待てばよいですか？禁止を解くには？

*禁止には時間切れがありません*。これはずっと待つだけでは解除されないということです。
つまり、あなたが動かなければ、二度と投稿が許可されることはありません！**この禁止を止めるには、ほかの手段で貢献するしかありません**。

モデレーターでも禁止は解除できません。

**他のことをする前に、存在している投稿を修正してください**！上記の通り、マイナス投票はあなたを禁止に導きます。解除するためにできる最良のことは、他人の反論に対処することです。
過去の質問はわかりにくかったりしませんか？努力をうまく示せていますか？読みにくいフォーマット、わかりにくいタイトルだったり、あまりにも長すぎたり、短すぎたり... **なら直しましょう**！

**投稿は削除しないでください**。上記の通り、（削除された時が三十日未満の時に）削除しても何の解決にも至りません。とにかく直してください！いくらかの条件付きで、あなたの削除された質問の一覧が見れます。

質問を禁止されたならば、プラス投票されるような良い回答を書くことでまた質問できるようになるかもしれません。しかし実際の基準は公開されていません。

もしあなたに禁止が間違いだという確信があるなら、右下のリンクから直接メールでお問い合わせください。しかし禁止の解除は最優先事項ではないです。

## 新しいアカウントを使って避けることはできますか？

無理です。自動禁止はアカウントよりも低いレベルで行われます。

## ほかのサイトで質問したら正しいサイトに移行されるはず！

移行先で質問が禁止されている場合、移行（migration）は不可能です。たとえオフトピックとしてクローズされていても、そのまま放置（か削除）されます。

## Meta Stack Exchangeでも同じようになりますか？

はい、しかし低評価の基準値はマイナス投票がMetaでは一般的なので、その基準値は下げられているようです。これはメインサイトでブロックされるとメタも使えなくなるという意味ではありません。

## アカウントはよい状態なのですが... なぜまだブロックされているのですか？

このBANはIPアドレスにも関連します。もし共有しているPC、もしくは同じIPを使っている人がたくさんいるのなら、使っている誰かが投稿を禁止されています。

他の場所から試してみると回復するかもしれません。

---

<sup>*1 Help vampireというのは、回答が見つかる、見つからないにもかかわらず助けてくれる！と期待しているひと。</sup>

Comment: 気になった点と改善案を列挙します。読みづらくてすみません。「利益を与えることをほのめかしています」→「利益を与えるということです」, 「これを施行する、」→「これを推し進め、」, 「一度」→(削除), 「多くの質問は」→「多くの質問が」, 「学習します」→「学習してください」, 「この禁止を止めるには、他の手段で貢献してください」→「この禁止が解除されるには、他の手段で貢献するしかありません」, 「エラー」→「誤り」, 「移行されました！」→「移行されるはず!」

Comment: すみません、もう1つ追加します。「このBANはIPアドレスも取得します。」→「このBANはIPアドレスにも関連しています。」

Comment: @masm ありがとうございます！