# パズルゲームの解法など、正答例を求める質問に回答するには？

Tags: 討議, 回答の仕方

[Can someone solve level 12 of this logic game](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/62893/9820)では、いわゆるパズルゲームの解法が分からず正解を求めた質問が上がっています。
※こちらはほぼ正答例に近いコメントから始まるコメントのやり取りで解決されています。

上記のように「あらかじめ特定の解答が用意されている問題」の正答例を求める質問には、どのような回答またはコメントすることが望ましいでしょうか。
パズルや穴埋め問題についての質問は、ヒントを出すことが難しい場合があると感じたので質問させていただきました。

質問で提示された問題の種類や宿題の丸投げに感じた場合など、ケースバイケースで判断は変わると思いますが、今回の例や類似の質問について対応方法のポリシーやご意見があれば今後の回答時の参考にさせていただきます。

以下は質問を書きながら思い浮かんだ対応案です。

- 直接の回答を避けてヒントやアドバイスにとどめ、それが思いつかない時は回答しない
- 巨大掲示板のネタバレスレッドに誘導する
- 質問者が求めるものは正答例なので、模範解答を回答する

Answer (score 5, accepted):

チャットで @nekketsuuu さんから[スポイラー](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/9820)の機能を教えていただきました。
教わった知識ですが自己回答として投稿します。
第三者が見ると困るネタバレ回答に限っては、スポイラー機能を活用して能動的に表示しないと見られないようにすれば解決すると思います。

下記の灰色部分にマウスオーバーすると元質問のレベル12の解答が表示されるのでご注意ください。

> [image: 解答例]

ところで質問を作成している中で「あらかじめ特定の解答が用意されている問題」かどうかの線引きは存外難しいと思いました。

`CodinGame`はゲーム？
`AIZU ONLINE JUDGE`は？
`paiza`の採用者向け問題を質問するのはルール違反？
`Robocode`の改良方法は質問して良いよね？

など、質問者と回答者双方の判断が適宜必要になるでしょう。
結局は質問者の理解度やどのような試行錯誤をしてきたか、本当に丸投げではないのかを探りながら最適な回答を模索するのが望ましいのではないでしょうか。