# もくもく会: 既存のナレッジベースを改善しましょう！ (開催済み)

Tags: 討議, 交流会, もくもく会

[@cubick](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/3060/cubick)、[@aki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/14055/aki)、[@Yuki Inoue](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/754/yuki-inoue)の翻訳に感謝。

---

スタック・オーバーフローには[コミュニティモデレーション](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2517/14055)が必要だと強く思います:

> Stack Exchange サイトは、ユーザーが自己管理できるように設計されました。モデレーションの負担は複数の小さなタスクに分けられ、たくさんのモデレーションは一般ユーザーによって行われています。

このサイトで最も優れたモデレート機能の1つは、時間の経過とともに古くなったコンテンツを改善し、高品質で正しい情報を維持できることです。既存のナレッジベースの品質を維持する方法は3つあります:

- *既存の回答に改善編集を提案する:* 投稿に関するAPIの変更やSDKの更新があった場合、回答を正確かつ適切な状態に保つために編集を提案してみましょう。
- *新しい回答を投稿する:* いくつかの質問には、まだ (承認された) 回答が付いていないものがあります。これらに回答を投稿してみましょう。
- *関連性の低い質問や回答を削除する:* 投稿内容が古くなったり品質が低いものについて、コミュニティーメンバーによる投稿の改善も難しい場合には、それらを削除して整理することも検討してください。

#### 私たちのナレッジベースで何が起こっているのか、どのように確認できますか？

ナレッジベースの現在の品質を理解するのに役立つ指標の1つは、回答済みの質問の割合と質問に対する回答の比率を調べることです。

> 回答済みの質問とは、"承認された回答" または "プラス評価の回答" が付いた質問です。

90% を超えていることがここでの目標です。

> 質問に対する回答の比率とは、1つの質問に対して付いた "回答の平均数" で定義されます。

こちらは 2.5 以上なら素晴らしい状態だと言えるでしょう。

[stackexchange.com/sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) にアクセスすることで、(他のネットワークサイトを含め) これらの数値を確認することができます。スタック・オーバーフローの場合、回答済みの質問は 77% 、質問ごとの回答率は 1.2 です。これらの数値は決して悪いものではなく、他の関連サイトでも一般的なのでしょう。それと同時に、私たちはこの数字をさらに高めることもできるでしょう。=)

#### 多くのユーザーによる小さな貢献の積み重ねが、コミュニティのナレッジベースをより良いものにしていきます

別の多言語サイトでは、時々既存のコンテンツを再訪するという素晴らしい伝統があります。考え方は簡単です: "回答済み質問" の割合と "質問に対する回答の比率" を改善するために協力します。一定の期間 (通常は一週間程度) 、手助けをしたいユーザーは、[未解決の質問一覧](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Unanswered) をチェックしに行きます:

1. 質の高い質問な場合:

   - 良い回答が付いている場合には、その回答にプラス票を投じる。
   - まだ回答が無い場合や質の低い回答しかない場合には、新しい回答を投稿する。
2. 質の低い質問な場合:

   - 改善できる場合には、編集提案をして ステップ1 に戻る。
   - 改善が難しい場合には、マイナス票を投じるか "質問のクローズ" に投票する。
     (その後、 [放棄された投稿を削除するのは コミュニティユーザー のお仕事です](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/roomba))

### もくもく会を開催しましょう！

"質問の回答率" と "質問に対する回答の比率" を上げることを目的として、もくもく会を開催することについてどう思いますか？参加してみませんか？もし実施する場合、イベントの希望日はいつがいいでしょうか？（7月には23～26の4連休があります）。どれくらいの期間でイベントを実施しますか？ (週末のみ、または一週間程度 etc)

補足として、回答率90% や回答比率 2.5 を一気に目指す、という意図ではありません。これらの数値は、インジケーターであって、方向性を確認するためのものです。我々が本当にやりたいことは、一歩ずつ、既存のナレッジベースを改善することです: 一人一人のユーザーが、イベント中に少しずつの改善を行うことによって、トータルの質が大きく改善するであろうと確信しています。

皆さんからの意見をお待ちしています！

**参考:**
"もくもく会" について、および直近で実施した「オンラインもくもく会」の様子です。

- [2020年 2月22日 (土) 13時～ もくもく会を開催しました！](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3235)

Answer (score 7):

スタック・オーバーフローのコミュニティの皆さんでオンラインもくもく会を開催します！

### 開催日時：

2日間開催します

#### 1日目 ファシリテーター : [payaneco](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/9820/payaneco)さん

2020年7月24日（金）13:00 - 17:00 （日本時間 JST  ）
2020年7月24日（金）07:00 - 11:00 （モスクワ時間 MSK ）
2020年7月23日（木）21:00 - 01:00 （太平洋夏時間 PDT ）

#### 2日目 ファシリテーター : [nekketsuuu](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/19110/nekketsuuu)さん

2020年7月25日（土）13:00 - 17:00 （日本時間 JST  ）
2020年7月25日（土）07:00 - 11:00 （モスクワ時間 MSK ）
2020年7月24日（金）21:00 - 01:00 （太平洋夏時間 PDT ）

途中入退室 OKです。日本国内外どこからでも参加が可能です。

### スケジュール：

13:00 - 13:30 開会式 -> ゆるりと集まって「今日の目標」を宣言する
15:00 - 15:30 もぐもぐ時間 -> 休憩 
16:30 - 17:00 閉会式および反省会 ->「今日の成果」や「感想」を適当に書き込む

### もくもくすること：

今回のフォーカスは **"質問の回答率"** と **"質問に対する回答の比率"** を上げることです。まとまった時間を用意してみんなで一人ひとり何かに取り組むことがもくもく会の目標ですので、スタック・オーバーフローに関することなら基本的に何をしても OK です。以下に題材の例を挙げてみます

- 質の高い質問や回答を見つけてプラス票を投じる。
- まだ回答が無い場合や質の低い回答しかない場合には、新しい回答を投稿する。
- 質問や回答を見ながら、自分の開発を進める。良い回答をシェアする。
- 投票をできるだけ積極的に行い、「[市民の務め](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty)」バッジ獲得を目指す。

### 集合場所：

SOja交流会チャット
https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95328/soja
（音声はありません）

チャットログ: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55042330#55042330

Twitterハッシュタグ： [#SOもくもく](https://twitter.com/search?q=%23SO%E3%82%82%E3%81%8F%E3%82%82%E3%81%8F)

Answer (score 4):

コロナの影響もあって外出しづらい状況ではありますが、あくまで休日に実施するのであれば私は (前回の3時間を踏まえて) 今回は **13時 ～ 17時頃** での実施を提案します。

この中には (若干のジョークも交えて) 途中休憩の「もぐもぐタイム」を設けてみるのはどうでしょうか？
(15時頃から30分 ～ 1時間程度)

小休止の間に、前半での進捗を自分で振り返ってみたり、作業中に気づいた疑問や問題点などをチャットでシェアするのです。もちろん随時チャットへの投稿はOKですが、新着メッセージがあるか気にしながらだと作業に集中しづらい人もいるでしょう。

「もぐもぐタイム」では、作業の手を休めてチャットに耳を傾ける時間、という意味合いもあります。
(もちろんぶっ続けで作業した方が効率のいい人は、無理をしない程度にそのまま続けてもOK)

---

#### 以下余談

もくもく会に役立つかもしれないブラウザのユーザースクリプトを紹介してみます。

- [SE Preview on hover](https://greasyfork.org/ja/scripts/27332-se-preview-on-hover)

  SEサイト内の投稿リンクにマウスを重ねると、リンク先のプレビューが表示できます。
  頻繁に戻ったり進んだりをする必要が減るので便利です。回答がついている場合には、
  もちろんそれらも表示できます。
- [Stack Overflow Extras (SOX)](https://github.com/soscripted/sox)

  SEサイト内の "かゆいところに手が届く" 系の機能を詰め込んだスクリプトです。
  設定項目は非常に多いですが、例えば「投稿の編集時にプレビューを横並びに出来る」等。

Answer (score 4):

スタック・オーバーフローにはさらに良い回答とプラス票が必要です！よって私も今回のもくもく会に参加したいと思います =）残念ながら私は日本語を話せないのですが、プラス票またはマイナス票を投じることが可能です（Google翻訳がここでしっかりと助けてくれることを願っています）。python、c、c++ タグの質問と回答に焦点を当てる予定です。

私たちのコミュニティナレッジベースを維持することは、サイトを使用する仲間たち、そして検索してやってくる人々にとって、とても重要です。コミュニティのナレッジベースを改善するためにもくもく会に参加することは素晴らしいことなのです！

皆さんのご参加をこころよりお待ちいたしております！

Answer (score 3):

> "質問の回答率" と "質問に対する回答の比率" を上げることを目的として、もくもく会を開催すること

開催に賛成します！
とても良い目的です。

> 希望日

希望日はありません。
日程に応じて可能であれば参加します。
時差の関係もありますが、24日など大人数が参加しやすいスケジュールに賛成します。

> どれくらいの期間でイベントを実施

イベントの期間は、難しい問題です。
期間が長すぎるとチャットが閑散として間延びしてしまいます。
しかし短すぎると難問への回答などの大きなことを成し遂げることができません。

前回のもくもく会に参加した時の個人的な感想です。

- 3時間はあっという間だった

  - 目標件数の半分も達成できなかったけれど、作業自体は集中してできた
- 議論が始まると盛り上がるが、会話の無い時間も案外多い

  - しかし集中して課題に取り組む会話のない時間があることで、議論も盛り上がったのではないか
- 分からないことを質問するとすぐに誰かが答えてくれるのはありがたかった

  - 例えば[スポイラー](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3271/9820)などのメタ的な活用方法の使い方
- 未回答の質問をリスト化する自作のpythonスクリプトは役に立った

  - 質問のコメントなどを可視化するツールで埋もれている質問を発掘して回答を追加した

ということで、稚拙ですが他の方の議論の踏み台になりそうな案を置いておきます。

- 期間は1～2日間で行う。
- 1日間の場合は10時開始、18時終了として10時～10時半の開会式にゆるりと集まって「今日の目標」を宣言する。(2日間の場合は前日17時などに開会式をずらす)
- 17時～18時を閉会式および反省会として「今日の成果」や「感想」を適当に書き込む。

これによって間延びした日程や誰もいない状況を防ぎながらある程度長い作業時間を確保します。
(1時間ごとに「ポモドーロタイム」でも設定して、ファシリテーターが適当な会話をばら撒く手法も考えましたが、うまくやらないと効果が出ない気がします)

活動報告の時に「もくもく会の前と後で、今月の回答率はn%からm%に上がりました」などの成果が目に見えると面白いかもしれませんね。
(あくまでも「面白いかもしれない」程度の思い付きです。成果を重視するよりも、みんなでワイワイする方が重要だと思います)