# もくもく会: 既存のナレッジベースを改善しましょう！

Tags: 討議, 交流会, もくもく会

調和を保ちながらコミュニティのナレッジベースの質を維持するのは簡単なことではありません。しかしそれが何であれ、ともに力を合わせれば達成できるのです✊

ようこそ皆さん！[もくもく会](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3355/)でお会いできて本当に嬉しいです。この2日間は、スタック・オーバーフローの回答率を改善することにフォーカスをおきたいと思います。イベントのファシリテーターは[@payaneco](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/9820/payaneco)さんと[@nekketsuuu](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/19110/nekketsuuu)さんです。

私たちの共有の目標を達成する方法の1つとして、[未解決の質問タブ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/unanswered)をクリックし、以下を行うことができます :

1. 質の高い質問である場合 :

   - 良い回答が付いている場合には、その回答にプラス票を投じる。
   - まだ回答が無い場合や質の低い回答しかない場合には、新しい回答を投稿する。
2. 質の低い質問である場合:

   - 改善できる場合には、編集提案をして ステップ1 に戻る。
   - 改善が難しい場合には、マイナス票を投じるか "質問のクローズ" に投票する。
     (その後、 [放棄された投稿を削除するのは コミュニティユーザー のお仕事です](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/roomba))

全ての小さな貢献に感謝します。 1つの回答や1つの投票が知識ベースをより良いものにしていきます。そしてそれが勝利へとつながるのです。

もくもく会でアドバイスを共有したり、仲間と交流したい場合には、こちらのチャットルームで行ってください。

24日と25日にご参加いただけますこと、本当に嬉しく思います。頑張ってやってみましょう！ =）

Answer (score 6):

私たちが集まり、ナレッジベースの改善に取り組めたのは素晴らしいことです。もくもく会の2日間では、次の活動が行われました :

- 48 件の回答
- 268 回の投票

私たちはこれまでの活動に誇りを持つべきだと思います。参加してくれた皆さん、どうもありがとう！ファシリテーター役の[@payaneco](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/9820/payaneco)と[@nekketsuuu](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/19110/nekketsuuu)に、感謝を申し上げます！主導くださりありがとうございました！

ぜひまた、開催しましょう