# ヘルプセンターの 「質問が受け付けられなくなったのはなぜですか？」を改善したい

Tags: 討議, 完了, ヘルプ

ヘルプセンターの [私のアカウントからの質問が受け付けられなくなったのはなぜですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) を、以下に挙げる理由から改善したいです。

---

#### 全体的な表現の見直し

直訳なのか、分かりづらい表現が多いです。例えば末尾にある

現状:

> 回答を投稿しようとしたときに同様なメッセージがある場合は、[what to do about answer bans](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/answer-bans) (回答禁止のためにすべきこと) に関するガイドラインをご覧ください。

修正案:

> 回答を投稿しようとしたときに同様のメッセージが表示された場合は、[回答禁止になった場合にすべきこと](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/answer-bans) のガイドラインをご覧ください。

#### "質問を書くためのヒント" のリンク先

ヘルプセンターの [良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) へのリンクと合わせて、[英語版](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) ではいくつか「質問の書き方」を示した外部サイトへのリンクが提示されていますが、日本語版ではただのテキストだけになってしまっています。

英語版に揃えるよりも、**日本語で書かれた** ページヘのリンクを追加しませんか？例えば、時折コメントや回答時にも言及されることが多い以下のページなど。(他にも候補があればぜひ教えてください)

> 技術系メーリングリストで質問するときのパターン・ランゲージ
> https://www.hyuki.com/writing/techask.html

#### "投稿の書式設定" のリンク先

"Sandbox" については日本語メタにも [マークアップの練習場](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331) があるので、こちらへのリンクに差し替えたいです。

Answer (score 1):

一先ずこのように編集いたしました。

[image: help/question-bans]