# コメント欄のプレビューってできますか？

Tags: サポート, コメント

コメント欄でもいろいろ修飾ができる (**で強調とか) ようですが、質問欄や解答欄では入力中にも自動でプレビューができるのにコメント欄ではできないというか、されないようです。コメント入力中に自動プレビューってできるのでしょうか？できるならその方法を教えてください。

解答欄に入力してプレビューしてコピペ＋回答は破棄とかやっていますが、微妙に不便です。間違えて解答欄にコメント書いちゃいそうで危険。そもそも解答欄のマークアップとコメント欄のマークアップが同じかどうかもオイラ的には定かでないし・・・

Comment: 既にご存じかもしれませんが、コメント欄で使える Markdown は [こちら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) で確認できます。

Comment: MSE での関連討議: [Preview for comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9425/403540) / 提案としてはいったん却下扱いのようですが、ユーザー視点では「追加して欲しい」寄りに見えます。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

コメントのプレビュー機能はありません。また、回答で使える文法とコメントで使える文法は微妙に差異があるので回答欄だと完璧な再現にはなりません。（差異の例: [edit] と書くとコメント欄では編集画面へのリンクになりますが、回答欄だとなりません。）

一応、メタの https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341/19110 を練習場として使えます。プレビューではないので微妙に不便なのは変わらないのですが……。

Answer (score 2):

補足です。

> 解答欄では入力中にも自動でプレビューができる

という点なのですが、実はこのプレビューと実際の投稿のレンダリング結果には差異が有ります（特に日本語やいわゆる全角記号が含まれると、差異が生じるケースが多いです）。

つまり現在はMarkdownのレンダリングエンジンが3つ有ります。

- 本文のプレビュー
- 本文の実際の投稿
- コメント